# Moneybookers extension in Magento not working

Tags: php, magento, iframe, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 with custom theme and I am trying to setup Phoenix Moneybookers extension. On my localhost (XAMPP on Win 7) is everything working as it suppose to, but on my hosting it is not working at all.

In 4th step of checkout (Payment Information) are payment method images and instructions not loading and what is even worse, when I click Place Order button it redirects me to "http://mydomain.com/moneybookers/processing/payment/" where is just an empty page (with menus, footer ...) with no payment options(no Skrill iframe).

On my localhost it redirects me to "http://magento.localhost.com/moneybookers/processing/payment/" with successfully loaded Skrill iframe.

I have tried ideas from http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/55163/P0/ but with no success.

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you disable and enable the MoneyBookers extension block from the admin panel. Try reindexing the database after this.

Also check the manual for installing MoneyBookers, as you might missed to pass some element on the live site

Answer (score 2):

1) I'd start by stop using Windows for development; Then,

2) Check your browser (inspect element) to see if you forgot to push anything to live env;

3) In your server, check in Magento_Root/var/log/system.log which errors Magento is issuing;

4) Now check the logs of your Apache/Nginx and PHP. Usually on /var/log/name-of-application/

I hope it helps.